# Swapping variables in an equation

Tags: linear-transformations

Consider this function,

$$ f\left(\frac{ax+by}{a+b} \right) = \frac{af(x) + bf(y)}{a+b}$$

would it be correct to write ,

$$ f\left( \frac{ay+bx}{a+b} \right) = \frac{ a f(y) + bf(x)}{a+b}$$

Reasoning: the equation should even if you switch variables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure. Perhaps it might be easier to see if you make some intermediate substitutions. Let $x \mapsto p$ and $y \mapsto q$. Then

$$f\left(\frac{ax+by}{a+b} \right) = \frac{af(x) + bf(y)}{a+b}$$

becomes

$$f\left(\frac{ap+bq}{a+b} \right) = \frac{af(p) + bf(q)}{a+b}$$

Now let $p \mapsto y$ and $q \mapsto x$.

$$f\left(\frac{ay+bx}{a+b} \right) = \frac{af(y) + bf(x)}{a+b}$$

---

Alternatively, consider defining

$$g(x,y) := f\left(\frac{ax+by}{a+b} \right) = \frac{af(x) + bf(y)}{a+b}$$

Then if we were to swap $x$ and $y$, we would want to find $g(y,x)$, no? In doing so, then, the same variables are swapped in $f$'s equality, and so

$$g(y,x) = f\left(\frac{ay+bx}{a+b} \right) = \frac{af(y) + bf(x)}{a+b}$$